# How do you get blocks to hold NBT data between getting placed and broken?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you get a block to hold NBT data even after being placed and broken? I'm trying to make an adventure map, but a lever with the following code:

```
{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone"]}
```

can only be placed once before losing its data and being rendered unable to be placed again. Breaking the lever will give you a generic lever with no modifications. How do I get around this? How can I get a lever with the above NBT tag when it is broken?

Comment: if it's just one tag for a lever, you could /entitydata dropped lever items to have the CanPlaceOn tag.

Answer (score -1):

name the lever and then do a test for  command so you can have multiple levers